# Iterating through c array through function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, pointers

So I'm trying to figure out a way to iterate though an array passed into a function without knowing the size. I run into infinite loops with my code because the arrays are not NULL terminated. Since the array is turned into a pointer through the function, I cannot use sizeof(Array)/sizeof(int) to get the number of elements. Is there any way of doing this without NULL terminating my arrays?

My find function:

```
int find(const int* arr, int val)
{
    int pos = 0;
    while (arr != NULL)
    {
        if (*arr == val)
        {
            return pos;
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return -1;
};
```

My main:

```
int IntArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int index = find(IntArr, 4);
cout << "find(IntArr, 4)" << endl;
cout << "index: " << index << endl << endl;
```

Comment: If you don't know the size, you are SOL. If you guess, you will guess wrong. You say there's no terminator? Ok, then you have to pass the lenghth some other way, like in an additional argument.

Comment: Pass the size of the array, or use `std::array` or `std::vector` and pass by reference, as they know their size (or pass their begin and end iterators)

Comment: PS there is `std::find` function

Comment: You can never "NULL terminate" an array of `int` since `NULL` is a pointer value. This is the perennial problem with sentinel values, there is nothing you can put into an `int` that can't be interpreted as representing a valid `int`. If your array was only supposed to contain positive integers, then you could use a sentinel such as `-1`, but if it could contain any integer at all then no sentinel value is appropriate. `NULL` only works for pointers because C demands that `0` can never be a valid address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you could define a template function that accepts an array by reference

```
template <size_t N>

int find( const int ( & arr )[N], int value )
{
    int pos = 0;

    while ( pos < N && arr[pos] != value ) ++pos;

    return pos == N ? -1 : pos;
}
```

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::find` declared in header `<algorithm>`. You could write for example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//..

int IntArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
auto ptr = std::find( std::begin( IntArr ), std::end( IntArr ), 4 );
cout << "find( std::begin( IntArr ), std::end( IntArr ), 4)" << endl;
cout << "index: " << std::distance( std::begin( IntArr ), ptr ) << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Or just use `std::find` and pass two iterators.